# Remove 'empty cells' as factor level

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has one column and column has some data and some empty cells.
When I am checking the levels of that column it is showing three levels as it is taking empty cells as one level. I want to delete that level.
suppose I have

```
## editor note: starting from R 4.0.0, `stringsAsFactors` defaults to FALSE
## we now explicitly need `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`
df <- data.frame(fan = c("a","b"," ","a","b"), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

I have tried this code

```
droplevels(df)
```

but it is not working.

Comment: See [How to delete "" from factor levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73423683/4891738) for a simpler solution than answers below.

Answer (score 7):

'droplevels' does work. No need for complex code:

```
df <- data.frame(fan = c("a","b"," ","a","b")) 
df
#  fan
#1   a
#2   b
#3    
#4   a
#5   b

df$fan[df$fan==' ']=NA
df$fan = droplevels(df$fan)
str(df)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ fan: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 NA 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

When you read your file to R, you may avoid 'empty cell' being included as a factor level in the first place, by using the `na.strings` argument in `read.csv` (or in `read.xxx`). The `na.strings` argument defines "strings which are to be interpreted as `NA` values".

Here is an example where I read a text file (foo.csv) which I created from your 'df':

```
read.csv(file = "foo.csv", na.strings = " ")
#    fan
# 1    a
# 2    b
# 3 <NA>
# 4    a
# 5    b

str(as.factor(df2$fan))
# Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 NA 1 2
```

When the file is read the empty fields are now treated as `NA`, and 'blank' is thus not included as a factor level.

From `?read.table`: "Blank fields are [...] considered to be missing values in logical, integer, numeric and complex fields". However, in your data, the variable "fan" is a `character`. If you then have `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in `options` or in `read.xxx`, the `character` vector is converted to a `factor`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 df$fan[grepl("^\\s*$", df$fan)] <- NA #in case you have  c(" ", "", "a", "b", "   ")
```

#### Explanation

`^(|\\s+)$`- matches if there is an empty quote`''` or spaces within quotes`(" ", "    ", "      ")`.  Hence, more general.

```
  str(droplevels(df))
  #'data.frame':    5 obs. of  1 variable:
  #$ fan: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 NA 1 2
```

If you want to create a new dataset with the empty cells deleted

```
  df1 <- droplevels(df[!grepl("^\\s*$", df$fan),,drop=FALSE] )
  str(df1)
  #'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
  #$ fan: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: `\\s*` would be simpler than `(|\\s+)`

Comment: @hadley Thanks for the suggestion. I modified the code

Answer (score 2):

If you are using csv, this might help:

```
data<-read.csv(file = "data.csv", na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

I modified the prior response and added `, stringsAsFactors = T`
So, later it will not report `NA` in any subsequent analysis as in `Createtableone`

Comment: This is the correct solution if the problem actually has empty cells, as I did. For some reason I have not quite figured out, some blank cells in a dataset imported via readr::read.csv2 are not imported as an NA, and is rather retained as a blank cell without any stored value or NA. The factor column also did not record the blank value as any level, even though it did happen in different columns of the same import. Specifying blank cells explicitly as NA solved it.