# How to delete "" from factor levels?

Tags: r, factors, r-factor

My `gender` variable is a factor with three levels: `""`, `"Female"`, and `"Male"`. How can I remove `""` from its levels?

[image]

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the grey check mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
levels(all_trips_v2$gender)[1] <- NA
```

---

Here is a test:

```
x <- factor(c("", "F", "M"))

levels(x)
#[1] ""  "F" "M"

## the first level is ""; reset it to NA 
levels(x)[1] <- NA

x
#[1] <NA> F    M   
#Levels: F M

levels(x)
#[1] "F" "M"
```